# if [result of print substr($0,a,b)] then print $0

Tags: if-statement, awk, substr

I want to do something like this (I think the best choice is to use awk coding)

If the number in position between a and b match a condition, then I want to print all the
row.

I was trying to write a code such as this one

```
awk '{if(substr($0,a,b) print $0}'
```

but doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
# regexp condition
$ awk 'substr($0,a,b)~/condition/'

# string condition
$ awk 'substr($0,a,b)=="condition"'

# numeric condition
$ awk 'substr($0,a,b)>24'
```

If the substring matches the condition then the whole line is printed. The default block in `awk` is `{print $0}` so it can be omitted.